# CakePHP how to pass a parameter to controller?

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP I am trying to pass a simple parameter to my controller class method. However it looks like the parameter has to be visible in the URL. Can't I pass a parameter without it being visible in the URL?

My routing:

```
Router::connect(
    '/',
    array(
        'controller' => 'Pages',
        'action' => 'display'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array(
            'pageName' =>'home'
        )
    )
);
```

And my Controller method:

```
public function display($p_sPageName=null) {
```

Comment: You forgot to mention your cakephp version

Comment: Sorry, CakePHP version 2.3.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Router::connect(
    '/',
    array(
        'controller' => 'Pages',
        'action' => 'display',
        'home',
    ),
);
```

This should be a default route in a baked application and already present. The book has also a very good [section explaining the routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).

Also [follow the CakePHP coding standard](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html), this variable name $p_sPageName is bad. Nobody ever knows what $p_s means. [This is a very good read](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) about writing clean and readable code.

```
/**
 * Displays a static page
 *
 * @param string $pageName
 * @return void
 */
    public function display($pageName = null) { /*...*/ }
```

The doc block should tell you by "@param string $pageName" that it is a string not the variable name. Without documentation this becomes unreadable for everyone who does not know the naming conventions.

Comment: I once learned about this notation (p_s) being parameter (p) string (s), but I will look through that section.

Comment: Your routing works, thanks. Strange why it didn't work for me.

Comment: The doc block should tell you by "@param string $pageName" that it is a string not the variable name. Without documentation this becomes unreadable for everyone who does not know the naming conventions.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. I have just followed your advice and changed my variable names for the current project.